# How to build an array of Way Points dynamically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-waypoints

From a WebAPI I am getting the below array.

```
[
    {        
        "Latitude": "-38.080528",
        "Longitude": "144.363098"
    },
    {       
        "Latitude": "-38.080528",
        "Longitude": "144.363098"
    },
    {       
        "Latitude": "-37.844495",
        "Longitude": "144.873962"
    },
    {
        "Latitude": "-37.785911",
        "Longitude": "144.846497"
    },
    {
        "Latitude": "-37.720763",
        "Longitude": "144.978333"
    },
    {       
        "Latitude": "-37.777228",
        "Longitude": "144.95636"
    }
]
```

How can I construct an array of Way-Points in JavaScript using that at run-time.

The expected output should match the below

```
var wayPointsArray = [
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.080528,144.363098) },
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.080528,144.363098) },
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.844495, 144.873962) },
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.785911, 144.846497) },
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.720763, 144.978333) },
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.777228, 144.95636) }
    ];

console.log(wayPointsArray);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do: (Of course you need to have http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js available in your page.)

```
var result = [];
for(i in data){
  var element = {location: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].Latitude,  data[i].Longit
  result.push(element);
}
console.log(result);
```